# Django 1.5 - Create two tables for groups and user permissions

Tags: django, django-1.5

I'm starting creating my next project. I'm creating first the extended user. When I run the syncdb, I notice that it creates two tables for groups and user_permissions (UserProfile and User models).

[image]

Is this the new default models of Django 1.5? Can I disallow it, not to create groups and user_permissions table for UserProfile model?

Answer (score 0):

After, two tests I figure out why my UserProfile model creates tables the same with User model.

```
//When I create UserProfile model I extend it by AbstractUser.
//Which results on creating tables the same with User model.
//So be aware when you use User model class, expect it will create multiple tables

class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    street = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    cell = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

I change my extended model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    cell = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```